# Why are all the methods in BlocObserver empty?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Looking through the class that defines `BlocObserver`, all the methods do not have any functionality defined. The `BlocObserver` does not inherit anything from any other class. It is only connected to the `Bloc` class by being created during instantiation of a `Bloc`.

How do the methods in `BlocObserver` have functionality when they are empty inside `BlocObserver`?

Read through the `BlocObserver` definition, and read through the `Bloc` definition.

Answer (score 0):

#### What to do

The way you are expected to use `BlocObserver` is described pretty well in [Core Concepts](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/coreconcepts?id=blocobserver).

Basically, as `BlocObserver` is an [abstract class](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#abstract-classes), you would extend it in your own class, providing implementations for the handler methods as appropriate for your use-case.

So, roughly:

```dart
class CustomObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);

    // Perform logic based on the change
  }
}
```

Then, you would assign an instance of this class as the static [observer](https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/Bloc/observer.html) on `Bloc`, for example:

```dart
Bloc.observer = CustomObserver();
```

After this point, you would expect any changes that propagate through `Bloc` to call your `CustomObserver.onChange()` method.

#### How this works

The pattern of providing some framework object a definition of the code you'd like to run when certain events happen is a pretty common one, so it's useful to come to grips with it. Usually (and also in this case) it's way simpler than it appears.

As discussed above, you provide a `BlocObserver` to `Bloc` by setting a static member. This means both that:

- you can only have one observer in the system at a time, and
- any code can access it directly by calling `Bloc.observer`

Then, when making state changes, you ensure you do so via an instance of [`BlocBase`](https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/BlocBase-class.html) (such as [`Cubit`](https://pub.dev/documentation/bloc/latest/bloc/Cubit-class.html)), which takes care of calling the appropriate method on our observer.

So, once again using Core Concepts as a base, when calling `CounterCubit().increment()`, the call stack looks like this:

- `CounterCubit.increment`
- `CounterCubit.emit`/`Cubit.emit`/`BlocBase.emit` (through inheritance)
- `CounterCubit.onChange`
- `BlocBase.onChange`
- `SimpleBlocObserver.onChange`

At this point, you're back in your own code, and you can see that `SimpleBlocObserver.onChange(...)` calls `super.onChange(...)`. No magic, just function calls.

Comment: `super.onChange` is calling the `onChange` method defined in the superclass which in this case is `BlocObserver`. When we assign the `BlocObserver` to a `Bloc` instance, is `super.onChange` referring to the `onChange` method in `Bloc` which is inherited from `BlocBase`?

Comment: @Mashewa short answer, no. `super.onChange` still invokes the (empty) `onChange` method of `BlocObserver`. Calling `super.onChange` is "required" through use of the [mustCallSuper](https://pub.dev/documentation/meta/latest/meta/mustCallSuper-constant.html) annotation. The place where you (as the developer) put the logic you want to handle the `onChange` event is after that call to `super.onChange`, denoted by the `...`.

Comment: I actually have one more question... how does `super.onChange` know to automatically be called when a change occurs? Where is that logic implemented? Is the change in the `Change` parameter causing it to be called?

Comment: @Mashewa I added a description of what's happening under the hood.